# How to add @RequestBody to variables?

Tags: spring-boot, controller, postman

```
@PostMapping("/api/v1.0/{username}/forgot")
    public void forgotPassword(@PathVariable String username,@RequestBody String enteredPassword,@RequestBody String reenterPassword) {
        userServiceImpl.forgotPassword(username, enteredPassword, reenterPassword);
    }
```

**Here if the user wants to perform forgot password action he need to enter the password so how can i request user values from postman**

```
Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingPathVariableException: Required URI template variable 'email' for method parameter type String is not present]
```

**I am getting this error**

Answer (score 0):

**RequestBody** Annotation is generally used when you are not sure of the size of the data you will be sending to backend, for example : large JSON objects.
In your case I see you want to pass the username and password so will recommend you to go with **Request Headers** (preferably with some authentication methods to encrypt and decrypt the password, just to avoid plaintext password getting passed) instead of Request Body. There is a tab in postman from where you can pass the headers in key and value pairs. I would recommend you to check [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-http-headers) link illustrating the use of Request headers.

Comment: In my case i don't need to create authentication then how can i get user values through postman?

Comment: It would be pretty simple then, from postman you can pass them in header section and fetch in your backend app via @RequestHeader annotation using respective keys. Please refer the link I shared above, you'll find some examples.